# How to set 755 permissions in php after creating folder in the existing folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a following code in the Codeigniter controller to upload some files to "upload" folder in the remote ubuntu server. In this case there is created a new folder named as officer_id in the upload folder when upload files and should be applied 755 permissions to it. Otherwise rejected to upload the files.

```
 public function addFiles()
        {

            $this->checkPermissions('add', 'officer');
            $bc = array(array('link' => '#', 'page' => 'Attachments'));
            $meta = array('page_title' => 'Officers - Files', 'bc' => $bc);
            $this->data['officer'] = $this->Officer_model->getOfficer();


            $this->form_validation->set_rules('officer', "Officer", 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
                $files = $this->multi_upload($_FILES['file'], './uploads/' . $this->input->post('officer'));
                if (!empty($files)) {
                    foreach ($files as $fname) {
                        $fdata[] = array(
                            'officer' => $this->input->post('officer'),
                            'file_name' => $fname,
                            'status' => 1,
                        );
                    }
                    if ($this->db->insert_batch('tbl_officer_files', $fdata)) {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Officer Attachments Updated Successfully ..!!');
                        redirect('officer/addFiles');
                    } else {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Officer Attachments Updation Failed ..!!');
                        redirect('officer/addFiles');
                    }

                }
            }
            $this->render('officer/addFiles', $meta, $this->data);

        }

        public function saveUpload()
        {
            $this->multi_upload($_FILES['file']);
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                $inputFileName = './uploads/' . $data['upload_data']['file_name'];

                echo json_encode(array('success' => 'Files have been uploaded successfuly ..!!'));
            } else {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                echo json_encode($error);//array('error' => 'You are not allowed to upload such a file.',

            }
        }
```

How can I modified my code to enable this (Like chmod ......) ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: Well, have you tried, [chmod()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)?

Comment: @ Patrick. Can you show me the chmod() in the code ?

Comment: Whats the problem?

Comment: I gave you a link to the documentation.  Read it and make an attempt to implement it into your code.  You say that this code creates directories, but to be honest, I don't see anything in there that does that.

Comment: @ Pilan. The problem is that, how to modify the code to give 755 permissions to newly created folders in the upload folder when uploading files

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chmod("test.txt",0755);` to update the permission on file after uploading.

You can do this step by step as follow.

```
//this function returns uploaded file path
$uploadedd_file = file_upload_function(...); 

if(!file_exists($uploadedd_file)){


  die('Error in uploading file');

}

// Setting file permission
$set_permission = chmod($uploadedd_file,0755);



if(!$set_permission){

 // delete file if permission is not set
 unlink($uploadedd_file);

}



// optional step to validate
$new_permission = substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($uploadedd_file)), -4);

echo "all good goes here, file uploaded and permission is set to " . $new_permission;
```

Read more about `chmod`: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_chmod.asp
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php
I hope this works, let me know.

Comment: @ Dheeraj. In my example I modified as $inputFileName = './uploads/' . $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
   chmod($inputFileName,0755); But outs the same result

Comment: have you validated if the file uploaded successfully and does exist before setting up permission?

Comment: @ Dheeraj. When performing uploading option in my codeigniter view while selecting each files by this controller, the relevant folder has created in the upload folder. But is has dr--x-t permissions. So can not upload the files. If I give drwxr-xr-x permissions to newly created folder manually in the server, those files can be uploaded successfully. That's the problem.

Comment: @mcode You may find the [umask](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) functionality useful. Based on your permissions dr--x-t, I suspect you are executing PHP in a shared environment where this functionality maybe intentionally limited.

Comment: @ Alex Barker. I read the unmask functionality. And modified my code as follows. $files = $this->multi_upload($_FILES['file'], './uploads/' . $this->input->post('officer'));   
   chmod("./uploads/", 0755);. The the following messages out. Message: mkdir(): Permission denied, Message: chmod(): No such file or directory, Message: chmod(): Operation not permitted

Filename: controllers/Officer.php

Line Number: 413. Can you show me the modified code ?

Comment: I think you should give www-data sufficient permission to writable folder of your server. So it can fluently read write and thus update permission. If possible manually `chown www-data folder/path`